# Output value in Excel if MAX is TRUE

Tags: excel, if-statement, max

I have a table where I log currency values per day. I have a column where I sum all the values per month.
I want to have a cell where output the name of the month with the MAX value for the whole table.
I'm pretty sure I can get what I need by using a Pivot Table, but sadly I'm a complete moron when it comes to Pivot Tables, couldn't get one done correctly to safe my life!!

Please help!

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You can use `VLookup()` worksheet function for that: calculate the maximum value, and use `VLookup()` to find the corresponding name.

Comment: What if the max occurs more than once?

Answer (score 0):

1) First select the table where the currency values are written.
2) then go to the Pivot table and select by the column name 
3) Now use filter by use the month column and the max function for the currency value column.
You will get it try it